# NodeJS for loops with Mongo / HTTP call firing late

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loops, http

I'm fairly new to NodeJS and am still trying to wrap my head around the async nature of it, as well as when things are fired.

I've labeled each of the loops in the order that I expect them to fire with console.log() messages below. There are 4 loops in total that I expect to iterate in order.

When I hit the 'test call' end point, I begin by iterating through a list of data.

```
exports.testCall = function (req, res) {
  var list = myData;

  // Iterate through each list item and update MongoDB
  for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    var country = list[i].country;
    var codeGroups = list[i].codes;
    console.log('Loop #1');
    for (var j=0; j<codeGroups.length; j++) {
      console.log('Loop #2');
      queryAndUpdateCodeGroup(codeGroups[j], country);
    }
  }
}
```

For each of the above 'codeGroups', I want to run a process that makes a call to my HTTP client, retrieves the data for that code group, and then update my MongoDB with that data.

```
function queryAndUpdateCodeGroup(group, country) {

  myHTTPClient.itemLookup({
    browseGroup: group,
    country: country
  }).then(function success (results) {
      console.log('Loop #3');
      for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
        var childrenArray = results[i].childArray;
        var subCatArray = [];
        var id = results[i].currentID;
        var icon = '';
        var name = getNameByCode(country, results[i].currentID);

        for (var j=0; j<childrenArray.length; j++) {
          subCatArray.push({name: childrenArray[j].name, itemID: id, icon: ''})
        }

        checkItem(name, id, icon, subCatArray);
      }
  }).catch(function error (err) {
        console.log('ERR: ', JSON.stringify(err));
        return err;

      handleError(res, err);
  });

}
```

Once the HTTP request is successful, I run this checkItem function which will either create a new entry in Mongo or will update an existing entry. Once this is complete, I want to start the process over for the remaining results in "loop #3". When Loop #3 has completed, I want to return to Loop #2 and repeat until this has completed for loop #2. When loop #2 has completed, I want to repeat this process in loop #1.

```
function checkItem(name, id, icon, subcats) {
  console.log('Loop #4');
  MyCategories.findOne({itemID: id}, function (err, cat) {

    if (cat === null) {
      console.log('ADDING NEW ITEM: ', name);
      var newItem = new MyCategories({
        name: name,
        itemID: id,
        icon: icon,
        subCats: subcats
      });

      newItem.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          handleError(err);
          return;
        }
      })
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log('New Item Success: ', newCatSuccess);
      });
    } else {
      //Update item with latest info
      var conditions = { itemID: currNodeId };
      var update = { $set: { subCats: subcats }}; 
      MyCategories.update(conditions, update, function (err, updated) {
        if (err) {
          handleError(err);
        } else {
          console.log('ITEM HAS BEEN UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY.');
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Loop #1, and loop #2 seem to fire back and forth until completion, but loop #3 fires after #1 and #2 have completed, and #4 doesn't fire at all. How can I 'wait' until each step has completed before I continue on?

Comment: Just looking at the code my guess is that your call to checkItem happens before the data is pushed to subCatArray. Use any flow control technique to solve this. One way that works is to put the call to checkItem inside the loop and run it only when the loop is done if(j == childrenArray.length -1){ call checkItem here}.

Comment: @Tiramisu Good thought, but I tried it and still was unable to hit the checkItem call.

Comment: I read more carefully and you need to implement a flow control pattern that allows you to do things in sequence. A good one for that is streams or eventEmitters.

Comment: Before looking at streams or event emitters, I'd look at an async library like ... [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/). For example, you can provide a list of things to iterate over, an async function to apply to those things, and a final callback to invoke when all things have been iterated over.